# Why "word-wrap" css style doesn't work inside a <table> (GWT)?

Tags: css, gwt

We got this css to make a long string (without any space in it, URL for example) to fall into many new lines rather than just show 1 line:

```
.wordWrap{  word-wrap:break-word;  }
```

in .xml file

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>
          <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="myPanel" addStyleNames="{style.wordWrap}" > <g:Label text="Aaaaaa..very long string without any space in it... aa"> <g:/HTMLPanel>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This does not work.

However, if we remove the `<table>` then it work fine

So
Why "word-wrap" css style doesn't work inside a  (GWT)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found an answer

```
<table cellspacing="3" style="width: 100%; word-wrap:break-word; table-layout: fixed;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `white-space` property? This will solve your problem.

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

If above css doesn't work then try other combination of `white-space` property.

Read more about [CSS white-space Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp).

Comment: thax for ur answer but it didn't work. The word-wrap:break-word; table-layout: fixed;" work but it really ugly

Comment: Have you tried other combination of white-space property?

Comment: i think the simplest option is not to put into a <table> then we can solve the problem

Comment: But why are using `table`? Is it required to layout? I don't know but you can try with `FlexTable` also in place of `table`

Comment: Cos it quick to use <table>, maybe I will try Flextable or Grid